# Coordinates of Leaflet.Draw Polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

How to get the coordinates of the polygon on mouseClick, so I have all the coordinates of corners of the polygon? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a mouseevent 'click' (left) or 'contextmenu' (right) to a layer. (Polygon, marker, ...)

```
polygon.on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.getLatLngs());
})
```